# Stack grouped xAxes in bar chart

Tags: javascript, chart.js, chart.js2

I'm using Chart.js 2.7.0 and I'd like to make bar stacked by xAxes, but grouped by type.

Let's say I have something like this:
[image]

I would like to stack values 49 and 59 in one bar and 29 with 32 together.

When I'm using options stacked true it stack everything...
It becomes: [image]

When I tried to add xAxisID to dataset then second dataset with id x-axis-1 is hidden and not visible at all. X-Axis looks like is duplicated...
Look at snippet to see it.

```js
 var ctx = document.getElementById("chart1").getContext('2d');
 var ctx2 = document.getElementById("chart2").getContext('2d');
 var labels = [
      "2018_4",
      "2018_5",
      "2018_6",
      "2018_7",
      "2018_8",
      "2018_9",
      "2018_10",
      "2018_11",
    ];
 var data = {
    "labels": labels,
    "datasets": [
    {
      "label": "t1",
       xAxisID: "x-axis-0",
      "data": [
       29,19,26,28,20,21,11
      ],
      backgroundColor: 'blue'
    },
    {
      "label": "t1_SUM",
       xAxisID: "x-axis-0",
      "data": [
       32,29,36,38,30,31,31
      ],
      backgroundColor: 'red'
    },
    {
      "label": "t2",
      xAxisID: "x-axis-1",
      "data": [
      49,37,39,40,15,34,36,52
      ],
      backgroundColor: 'blue'
    },
     {
      "label": "t2_SUM",
      xAxisID: "x-axis-1",
      "data": [
      59,47,49,50,25,44,46,62
      ],
      backgroundColor: 'red'
    }
    ]
  };
  new Chart(ctx, {
  type: "bar",
  data: data,
  options: {
    scales: {
      xAxes: 
      [
      {
       stacked: true,
       id: "x-axis-0",
      },
       {
       stacked: true,
       id: "x-axis-1",
      }
      ],
    }
  }});
  
   var data2 = {
    "labels": labels,
    "datasets": [
    {
      "label": "t1",
      "data": [
       29,19,26,28,20,21,11
      ],
      backgroundColor: 'blue'
    },
    {
      "label": "t1_SUM",
      "data": [
       32,29,36,38,30,31,31
      ],
      backgroundColor: 'red'
    },
    {
      "label": "t2",
      "data": [
      49,37,39,40,15,34,36,52
      ],
      backgroundColor: 'blue'
    },
     {
      "label": "t2_SUM",
      "data": [
      59,47,49,50,25,44,46,62
      ],
      backgroundColor: 'red'
    }
    ]
  };
  
   new Chart(ctx2, {
  type: "bar",
  data: data2,
  options: {
    scales: {
      xAxes: 
      [
      {
       stacked: false,
      }
      ],
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="chart1"></canvas>
<canvas id="chart2"></canvas>
<canvas id="chart3"></canvas>
```

From this snippet I want to connect

- t1 and t1_SUM
- t2 and t2_SUM

Answer (score 0):

Ok,

I misread documentation.
I should use stack option in dataset and then it is working.
Sorry for troubles...